# Problems with $cordovaOauth in twitter Ionic app

Tags: angularjs, twitter, ionic-framework

I want to make a twitter feed ionic application. But have a problem. After the starting app it should show $cordovaOauth authorization window, something like this:
[what shood i see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reQxQ.jpg)

But i have : 
[what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47ElX.jpg)

I tried to do it by many wariants. 
E.g:

```
    ionic start devdactic-twitter blank
cd devdactic-twitter
bower install ng-twitter-api --save
bower install ngCordova#c3634c64090fa11c3e6bab3fcdc29712d3ecb965 --save

    cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

Load libraries:

```
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ng-twitter-api/dist/ng-twitter-api.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/sha1.js"></script>

angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'ngTwitter'])
```

View:

```
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller='AppCtrl'>
  <ion-pane>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
      <h1 class="title">My Twitter Feed</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content class="has-header padding">
      <div class="list">
        <div class="item item-input-inset">
          <label class="item-input-wrapper">
            <input type="text" placeholder="My tweet..." ng-model="tweet.message" ng-maxlength="140">
          </label>
          <button class="button button-small" ng-click="submitTweet()">
            Tweet
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ion-refresher on-refresh="doRefresh()"></ion-refresher>

      <div ng-show="home_timeline.length == 0">Loading tweets...</div>

      <div ng-repeat="entry in home_timeline" class="list card">
        <div class="item item-avatar">
          <img ng-src="{{entry.user.profile_image_url}}"/>
          <h2>{{entry.user.name}}</h2>
          <p>{{correctTimestring(entry.created_at) | date:'medium'}}</p>
        </div>

        <div class="item item-body">
          <p ng-bind-html="entry.text"></p>
          <img ng-if="entry.extended_entities" ng-src="{{ entry.extended_entities.media[0].media_url }}" style="width: 100%;"/>
        </div>

      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-pane>
</body>
```

AppCtrl:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPlatform, $twitterApi, $cordovaOauth) {});
```

then ( i enter here my key and secret) :

```
var twitterKey = 'STORAGE.TWITTER.KEY';
var clientId = 'yourConsumerKey';
var clientSecret = 'yourConsumerSecretKey';
var myToken = '';

$scope.tweet = {};

$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  myToken = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(twitterKey));
  if (myToken === '' || myToken === null) {
    $cordovaOauth.twitter(clientId, clientSecret).then(function (succ) {
      myToken = succ;
      window.localStorage.setItem(twitterKey, JSON.stringify(succ));
      $twitterApi.configure(clientId, clientSecret, succ);
      $scope.showHomeTimeline();
    }, function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  } else {
    $twitterApi.configure(clientId, clientSecret, myToken);
    $scope.showHomeTimeline();
  }
});
```

functions for controller:

```
$scope.showHomeTimeline = function() {
  $twitterApi.getHomeTimeline().then(function(data) {
    $scope.home_timeline = data;
  });
};

$scope.submitTweet = function() {
  $twitterApi.postStatusUpdate($scope.tweet.message).then(function(result) {
    $scope.showHomeTimeline();
  });
}

$scope.doRefresh = function() {
  $scope.showHomeTimeline();
  $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
};

$scope.correctTimestring = function(string) {
  return new Date(Date.parse(string));
};
```

I get this code in devdactic (you can find ngTwitter)

I spend a lot of time to find solution of this problem. Would you help me?
May be you have another variants how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can access directly from https://dev.twitter.com/overview/documentation , you need to call $http specified method, parameter and don't forget to include header in which has auth signature.